# Hadoop: the ip of slave is not correct

Tags: hadoop

**1.Host configuration:**

```
 127.0.0.1          localhost  
 192.168.1.3        master  
 172.16.226.129     slave1
```

**2.slaves file:**

```
slave1
```

**3.JPS:**

```
zqj@master:/usr/local/nodetmp$ jps
5377 Jps
4950 SecondaryNameNode
4728 NameNode
5119 ResourceManager

zqj@slave1:/usr/local/hadooptmp$ jps
2514 NodeManager
2409 DataNode
2639 Jps
```

**4.hadoop dfsadmin -report:**

```
zqj@master:/usr/local/nodetmp$ hadoop dfsadmin -report
DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated.
Instead use the hdfs command for it.

Configured Capacity: 22588977152 (21.04 GB)
Present Capacity: 16719790080 (15.57 GB)
DFS Remaining: 16719765504 (15.57 GB)
DFS Used: 24576 (24 KB)
DFS Used%: 0.00%
Under replicated blocks: 0
Blocks with corrupt replicas: 0
Missing blocks: 0
Missing blocks (with replication factor 1): 0

-------------------------------------------------
Live datanodes (1):

Name: 192.168.1.3:50010 (master)
Hostname: slave1
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 22588977152 (21.04 GB)
DFS Used: 24576 (24 KB)
Non DFS Used: 5869187072 (5.47 GB)
DFS Remaining: 16719765504 (15.57 GB)
DFS Used%: 0.00%
DFS Remaining%: 74.02%
Configured Cache Capacity: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used: 0 (0 B)
Cache Remaining: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used%: 100.00%
Cache Remaining%: 0.00%
Xceivers: 1
Last contact: Mon Jan 30 17:29:01 CST 2017
```

[Datanode in localhost:50070](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4dX4.jpg)

I want to know why the IP is not correct when the namenode is in the real machine and datanode is in the virtual machine. thanks!

**When I use virtual machine as the namenode, everything works well and ip is correct. is there anything necessary to configure in VMware like gateway or ip?**

Comment: So which type of cluster are you running is it pseudo mode or distributed

Comment: @siddharthajain disturbuted mode

Comment: Which version of Hadoop.Have you configured slave file ?

Comment: @siddharthajain hadoop 2.7.3. I have confirmed that slaves file is configured. You could search the key words "Wrong hadoop datanode" in stack overflow. The first of the search result is similar to my question. thank you for your patience.

Comment: That question is related hadoop 1.x In your case you do not have configure host file like he did you need to configure master file for name node

Comment: So my hosts file is wrong? As I know, the masters file is not necessary to configure  in hadoop 2.x.

Comment: 1.Configure all your hosts to use FQDN instead short names. 2.Fix hosts file including FQDN 3. Check every config file and replace IPs/shortnames by FQDN. 4. As your metadata database got inconsistent you'll have to reinstall ambari from the scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Put your slaves file in the master node. (NOT in the slaves node). I hope the hosts config is on master node.. This will fix the issue

Comment: I tried what you say, but it still doesn't work well. I have delete the slaves file in slave node.